# How can you implement WaterfallDialogs into a more than one app LUIS bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have multiple LUIS Apps that need to be used by my bot. I want LUIS to recognize the intents and begin a Waterfall Dialog accordingly.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far? This should be an easy solution, but no one will be able to assist you unless they can see what you've tried.

Comment: So I am using Javascript and Node.JS and I found that I should use the dispatch in order to recognize the intent from LUIS and take one direction (dialog) or another. And when this goes throug the intended dialog .js file it won't allow me to create a Waterfall Dialog.

Comment: In order to get a clear idea of where the implementation is going wrong, can you post your code?

Comment: The problem is that as I saw, you need a Dispatch (if you are using multiple apps in LUIS) and it has its own constructor but then you need a constructor as well for the Waterfall Dialogs and I don't exactly understand how they both can fit into my code